# Insensitive occurrences counter - JS

Tags: javascript, counter

I have a counter of occurences that is looking for a substring in a string, but it's case sensitive.
My actual code is :

```
count = (string.match(new RegExp(substring, 'gm')) || []).length;
```

For example, if the string contains the substring one time but with a more accent, the count will be equal to '0'.

Is there a way to create a case-insensitive counter please ?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what occurrences you want to match? What does *but with a more accent* mean in this context? What is a *more accent*?

Comment: `var string = 'dede',
substring = 'dédé';
console.log((string.match(new RegExp(substring, 'gm')) || []).length); //Output 0` This code output 0 as the substring contains accents and the string don't

Comment: Yes, you have to first exchange all accented chars for non-accented chars then

Comment: So there is no function, or a modification of my actual code to do that ?

Comment: Well, there is a modification of your actual code, and that is adding a call to some function that receives a string and returns it with the characters changed. There is no built-in feature for this

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could turn both strings to lowercase using `toLowerCase()` or using flag `i`(but keep in mind [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility)) . For accents, unfortunately you have to replace it individually to base string:

```js
var string = "AÁáéíóú";

var substring = "AAaeiou";

var r = new RegExp("")

string = string.replace(/Á|É|Í|Ó|Ú/gi, function(m){
    if(m=="á") return "a"
    if(m=="é") return "e"
    if(m=="í") return "i"
    if(m=="ó") return "o"
    if(m=="ú") return "u"

    if(m=="Á") return "a"
    if(m=="É") return "e"
    if(m=="Í") return "i"
    if(m=="Ó") return "o"
    if(m=="Ú") return "u"
})

var count = (string.match(new RegExp(substring, 'gmi')) || []).length;

console.log(count)
```

If you have also **ñ**, you have to change it individually.

You could also use [.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize), but does not work in IE

```js
var string = "AÁáéíóú";

var substring = "AAaeiou";

var r = new RegExp("")

string = string.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/gi, "")

var count = (string.match(new RegExp(substring, 'gmi')) || []).length;

console.log(count)
```

Comment: Sure, but i'm talking about accents : `var string = 'dede',
substring = 'dédé';
console.log((string.match(new RegExp(substring, 'gm')) || []).length); //Output 0` This code output 0 as the substring contains accents and the string don't